# If you have a link on the popup.html, can the website receiving the call tell it came from a Chrome Extension?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, hyperlink

I have a Chrome extension that includes links to another page.

Can the website receiving those calls tell if the user came from clicking on a link in a Chrome extension?

If so, if there a way to avoid this?

Comment: No, it can't. You can verify it by using devtools or by setting your `<a>` element's href to an [online header inspector](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending).